# Is there a way to maintain a connection to a restful web service?

Tags: java, performance, web, connection, microservices

I'm working on an application which is a monolith.  We have some features in our roadmap that I think would fit into a microservices architecture and am toying around with building them as such.

My problem: the application processes ~150 requests per second during peak times. These requests come in on raw TCP/IP connections which are kept alive at all times.  We have very strict latency requirements (the majority of our requests are responded to within 25-50 milliseconds).  Each request would need to consume 1 to many microservices.  My concern is that consuming multiple restful web services (specifically creating/destroying the connection each time the service is consumed as well as TLS handshakes) is going to cause too much latency for processing these requests.

My question:  Is it possible (and is there a best practice) to maintaining the state of a connection to a restful web service while multiple threads consume that web service?  each request to consume the web service would be self contained but we would simply keep the physical connection alive.

Comment: Assuming you use HTTP as the transport protocol, you might get what you want if both client and server supports HTTP 2.

Answer (score 1):

JVM naturally pools HTTP connections for the `HttpURLConnection` (via http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html). So, it should be happening for JAX-WS and JAX-RS out of the box. Usually, other non-`HttpURLConnection` based frameworks (like netty) support http connection pooling as well. So it's very likely you don't need to worry about this by yourself in your code. You need to calculate how many connections you would need to pool though, but it's a configuration sort of thing.

You could check that TCP connections are not closed after getting an HTTP response by sniffing traffic from you application by `tcpdump` or `Wireshark` and checking if there is no TCP FIN happening after you get the result.